# Type mismatch en Android Studio Kotlin - String y Text View

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, textview

no encuentro cómo solucionarlo. Lo que ocurre es que no sé cómo convertir mi variable de tipo String a tipo TextView, para entonces poder asignar dicho valor al TextView original.

A modo resumen

```
private lateinit var tvResults : TextView
[...]
tvResults = findViewById(R.id.tv_results)
tvResults.visibility = GONE
[...]
btnDone.setOnClickListener {
val tvStringResult = "Your ID has been submitted successfully. Your data is: " + "\nDate of birth: $idBirth" + "\nGender: $idStringGender" + "\nNationality: $idStringNationality"
    
tvResults = tvStringResult        
tvResults.visibility = View.VISIBLE

}
```

He probado varias maneras, una de ellas, la siguiente:

```
tvResults.text = tvStringResult
```

no me da error en código, pero sí en el emulador (marcado en amarillo en la imagen)
[image: Imagen del emulador, error en amarillo]

Gracias por la ayuda

---

La variable idBirth está como "Android", aunque no sé por qué no me detecta que la estoy declarando como string, aquí pongo el código

```
btnDone.setOnClickListener {
        val idNumber: String = etId.toString().trim()
        val idBirth: String = idNumber.substring(0,7)
        val idGender: Int = idNumber[7].toInt()
        val idNationality: Int = idNumber[11].toInt()

        val idStringGender = if (idGender < 5) {
            "Female"
        } else {
            "Male"
        }

        val idStringNationality: String = if (idNationality == 0) {
            "SA Citizen"
        } else {
            "Permanent Resident"
        }

        val tvStringResult = "Your ID has been submitted successfully. Your data is: " +
                "\nDate of birth: $idBirth" +
                "\nGender: $idStringGender" +
                "\nNationality: $idStringNationality"

        tvResults.text = tvStringResult

        tvResults.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }
```

Comment: Lo que quieres en realidad es asignar un valor a la propiedad `text` del `TextView`. Hazlo así `tvResults.text = tvStringResult`

Comment: Supongo que lo que quieres hacer es asignar el string al texto del TextView

Answer (score 1):

No se puede convertir de `String` a `TextView`, si lo que quieres es asignar un `String` a tu `TextView`, realizalo de la siguiente forma:

```
textView.text = "hola cmf"
```

si lo que deseas es obtener el texto que se encuentra en el TextView lo realizas de la siguiente forma:

```
val texto: String = textView.text.toString()
```

---

Revisando tu código, lo que tratas de realizar aquí es incorrecto:

```
val tvStringResult = "Your ID has been submitted successfully. Your data is: " + "\nDate of birth: $idBirth" + "\nGender: $idStringGender" + "\nNationality: $idStringNationality"
    
tvResults = tvStringResult
```

ya que `tvResults` es un `TextView` y le deseas asignar una cadena de caracteres debes realizarlo de esta forma:

```
val tvStringResult = "Your ID has been submitted successfully. Your data is: " + "\nDate of birth: $idBirth" + "\nGender: $idStringGender" + "\nNationality: $idStringNationality"
tvResults.text = tvStringResult
```

Comment: Gracias @Jorgesys,

sé que lo que puse es incorrecto, pero estuve probando de mil maneras y todas me daban error, inclusive tu propuesta de 
tvResults.text = tvStringResult

Ahora os mando qué me dice el compilador, gracias

Comment: lo añado a la pregunta, gracias

Comment: La variable $idBirth tiene el valor "Android", debes en este caso revisar como estas declarando esta variable. @cmf

Comment: Gracias @Jorgesys,

he añadido código a ver si sacamos algo en claro.... aún soy bastante principiante, así que poco a poco voy aprendiendo. Aún me cuesta detectar errores y agradezco mucho la ayuda!